# How do NPCs heal our Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-series

In various Pokémon games, there are scenarios where we come out of a big fight (usually a boss fight) and an NPC heals our Pokémon for us. I know that Pokémon are healed in Pokémon Centers using special machinery, but is there any in-universe explanation to how these NPC can heal them at a seconds notice without any help?

[image: The player's Pokémon being healed by a nurse in FireRed/LeafGreen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is never addressed in games. You can imagine it being a vast supply of Max Revives, Max Restores, and Max Ethers if you want.

Comment: I was actually playing Pokémon Sun, and there the NPC (Lille) usually remarks that she carries a ton of above said items. So I imagine this is probably correct.

Comment: @IsmailHafeez If you have found an ingame source, feel free to post your own answer as well.

Comment: This is even more confusing in *Sword* and *Shield*, because IIRC they also heal all of the pokemon in your boxes... which as of *Sword/Shield*, you can access from anywhere at any time (except in battle). So just how many items are we expected to believe they used, exactly?

Comment: Something pointing towards this answer is that the usual sound effect when an NPC heals your Pokémon is that of an item (such as a Full Restore) being used, rather than the sound effect you get in a Pokémon Centre. Some NPCs do mention the methods they use, though - a channeler in Lavender Tower has enchanted the floor, the lady in Silph Co lets you rest in beds, etc.